# I have a problem with Flutter in the dio library (dio: ^4.0.0)

Tags: flutter

**DioHelper Class:**

[image: DioHelper Class]

**Dependecies:**

[image: dependencies]

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;

  static void initDio() {
    dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: 'https://newsapi.org/',
        receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Simply restart your editor and it should be fixed :)